# How to get only necessary value from multiple function return in Solidity?

Tags: return, blockchain, solidity

In a contract, I have a function that returns multiple variables.
It returns 7 variables but I only need one variable from it.
How can I take out only the necessary one?
Should I take all the variables and use only one?

```
interface IData {
   function getData() external view returns (unit d1, 
                                             string memory d2, 
                                             address d3, 
                                             unit d4, 
                                             string memory d5, 
                                             unit d6, 
                                             address d7);
}

contract Module {
   IData private keepData;
   constructor(address dataAddress) {
      keepData = IData(dataAddress);
   }

   function doSomething() external {
      unit d1;
      string d2;
      address d3;
      unit d4;
      string d5;
      unit d6;
      address d7;
      (d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7) = keepData.getData();
      // do something which only requires d5 data.
      // for other 6 variables except d5, they cause unused variable warning.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want a return value you can omit it, but you still need the commas. So if you only need `d5` from the returned values you can rewrite it like this:

```
function doSomething() external {
  string d5;
  (,,,,d5,,) = keepData.getData();
}
```

Comment: Is there documentation for this?